# Android: Pause OnTouchListener for performance

Tags: android, multithreading, ontouchlistener

I've got a OnTouchlistener on my ImageView and I've got the feeling like it's blocking the MainThread from time to time. I've got some Animations running, too, and eclipse sometimes tells me that a lot of frames were skipped.

I don't need to track every MotionEvent - it would be enough to call the onTouch-Method every 20-30 miliseconds.

Is there a way to set this?

Also I would like to mention that this onTouchListener is implemented in a special class that is only handling such Touch-Events; which means I could make this class extending Thread. But would this solve the problem if I put a `Thread.sleep(ms)` at the end of my onTouch-Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is what you want to accomplish:

add field `long lastTime = -1` to your listener class, then in `onTouch(MotionEvent event)` add:

```
if(lastTime < 0)
{
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
else
{
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime < 30) //how much time you decide
    {
        return true; //ignore this event, but still treat it as handled
    }
    else
    {
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
//your logic
```

Generally, merely adding a onTouchListener to a ImageView would never cause lag in your UI, unless you are doing a huge amount of calculations per event. If that is the case, I suggest you also look elsewhere for potential problems.

Also, beworker's advice is very good, don't call `Thread.Sleep()` as it halts everthing else in the thread.